# alternative to numpy.argwhere to speed up for loop in python

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have two data-sets as following:

ds1: a DEM (digital elevation model) file as 2d numpy array and,

ds2: which is showing areas (pixels) with some excess water in them.

I have a while loop that is responsible to spread (and change) excess volume in each pixel according to the elevation of its 8 neighbours and itself until the excess volume in each pixel is less than a certain value d = 0.05. Therefore in each iteration I need to find the index of pixels in ds2 where excess volume is greater than 0.05 and if there is no pixel left, exit the while loop:

```
exit_code == "No"
while exit_code == "No":
    index_of_pixels_with_excess_volume = numpy.argwhere(ds2> 0.05) # find location of pixels where excess volume is greater than 0.05

    if not index_of_pixels_with_excess_volume.size:
        exit_code = "Yes"
    else:
        for pixel in index_of_pixels_with_excess_volume:
            # spread those excess volumes to the neighbours and
            # change the values of ds2
```

the problem is that numpy.argwhere(ds2> 0.05) is very slow. I am looking for an alternative solution that is faster.

Comment: `argwhere` is just `where` with a `transpose` to turn the tuple of arrays into a 2d array.

Comment: Are you sure it's the `argwhere`, and not the `ds2>0.05` step, or more likely the iteration on all those `pixel`?

Comment: I did a cProfile and conclude this based on the number of the cumulative seconds written besides `argwhere`.

Comment: The `where` expression has to iterate over the array several time.  One to create the boolean array.  Then `np.count_nonzero` quickly counts the number of `True` values.  Finally `where` (actually `np.nonzero`) collects the indices of those values.  The `transpose` to `argwhere` should be a minor part of the action.  If `ds2` large compared to the number of True pixels, then this `where` action could dominate.

Comment: This is a very good idea. What worries me is the time that needs to be spent on modifying two arrays (ds2 and boolean) in each iteration instead of one array and hence loosing performance? As a side question: how about using scipy sparse matrices instead of booleans?

Comment: `nonzero` from a sparse matrix is almost trivial, but constructing a sparse matrix to start with is relatively slow.  Once constructed the fastest sparse operations are matrix multiplication.  Indexing, summing, iteration are all slower with sparse.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm reading the answer you kindly provided and trying to understand it. one other idea that came to my mind was slicing ds2 array into multiple parts and retrieving indexes in parallel. I'm not a professional so sorry if I talk very basics.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make a sample 2d array:

```
In [584]: arr = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
```

Find a small proportion of them:

```
In [587]: np.where(arr>.999)
Out[587]: 
(array([  1,   1,   1, ..., 997, 999, 999], dtype=int32),
 array([273, 471, 584, ..., 745, 310, 679], dtype=int32))
In [588]: _[0].shape
Out[588]: (1034,)
```

Time various pieces of `argwhere`:

```
In [589]: timeit arr>.999
2.65 ms ± 116 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [590]: timeit np.count_nonzero(arr>.999)
2.79 ms ± 26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [591]: timeit np.nonzero(arr>.999)
6 ms ± 10 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [592]: timeit np.argwhere(arr>.999)
6.06 ms ± 58.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So about 1/3 of the time is spend doing the `>` test, and the rest in finding the `True` elements.  Turning the `where` tuple into a 2 column array is fast.

Now if the goal was to just find the first `>` value, `argmax` is fast.

```
In [593]: np.argmax(arr>.999)
Out[593]: 1273    # can unravel this to (1,273)
In [594]: timeit np.argmax(arr>.999)
2.76 ms ± 143 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

`argmax` short circuits, so the actual run time will vary on when it finds the first value.

`flatnonzero` is faster than `where`:

```
In [595]: np.flatnonzero(arr>.999)
Out[595]: array([  1273,   1471,   1584, ..., 997745, 999310, 999679], dtype=int32)
In [596]: timeit np.flatnonzero(arr>.999)
3.05 ms ± 26.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [599]: np.unravel_index(np.flatnonzero(arr>.999),arr.shape)
Out[599]: 
(array([  1,   1,   1, ..., 997, 999, 999], dtype=int32),
 array([273, 471, 584, ..., 745, 310, 679], dtype=int32))
In [600]: timeit np.unravel_index(np.flatnonzero(arr>.999),arr.shape)
3.05 ms ± 3.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [601]: timeit np.transpose(np.unravel_index(np.flatnonzero(arr>.999),arr.shap
     ...: e))
3.1 ms ± 5.86 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This is the same as `np.argwhere(arr>.999)`.

Interesting, the `flatnonzero` approach cuts the time in half!  I didn't expect such a big improvement.

---

Comparing the iteration speeds:

Iteration on the 2d array from `argwhere`:

```
In [607]: pixels = np.argwhere(arr>.999)
In [608]: timeit [pixel for pixel in pixels]
347 µs ± 5.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Iterating on the tuple from `where` with the `zip(*)` transpose:

```
In [609]: idx = np.where(arr>.999)
In [610]: timeit [pixel for pixel in zip(*idx)]
256 µs ± 147 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Iterating on an array is often a little slower than iterating on a list, or in this case zipped arrays.

```
In [611]: [pixel for pixel in pixels][:5]
Out[611]: 
[array([  1, 273], dtype=int32),
 array([  1, 471], dtype=int32),
 array([  1, 584], dtype=int32),
 array([  1, 826], dtype=int32),
 array([  2, 169], dtype=int32)]
In [612]: [pixel for pixel in zip(*idx)][:5]
Out[612]: [(1, 273), (1, 471), (1, 584), (1, 826), (2, 169)]
```

One is a list of arrays, the other a list of tuples.  But turning those tuples into arrays (individually) is slow:

```
In [614]: timeit [np.array(pixel) for pixel in zip(*idx)]
2.26 ms ± 4.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Iterating on the flat nonzero array is faster

```
In [617]: fdx = np.flatnonzero(arr>.999)
In [618]: fdx[:5]
Out[618]: array([1273, 1471, 1584, 1826, 2169], dtype=int32)
In [619]: timeit [i for i in fdx]
112 µs ± 23.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

but applying `unravel` to those values individually will take time.

```
def foo(idx):    # a simplified unravel
    return idx//1000, idx%1000

In [628]: timeit [foo(i) for i in fdx]
1.12 ms ± 1.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Add this 1 ms to the 3 ms to generate `fdx`, this `flatnonzero` might still come out ahead.  But at its best we are talking about a 2x speed improvement.

Comment: I promise to upvote this in 17 hours (reached my limit for the day) (:

Comment: For 1D case (flattened arrays) I was expecting that further speed-up could have been achieved by pre-allocating the index array such as `r=np.arange(ds2.size)` and then simply applying boolean index to this array: `r[ds2.ravel() > threshold]`. This being in the loop could result in some gain. Strangely, this approach is slower than `flatnonzero(ds2 > threshold)`. Any ideas why?

Comment: plus1 for perseverance and hard work and a better answer than mine!

Answer (score 3):

`np.where(arr> 0.05)` and `(arr > 0.05).nonzero()` are ~22-25% faster in my tests.

For example:

```
while exit_code == "No":
    index_of_pixels_with_excess_volume = numpy.where(ds2 > 0.05)

    if not index_of_pixels_with_excess_volume[0].size:
        exit_code = "Yes"
    else:
        for pixel in zip(*index_of_pixels_with_excess_volume):
```

However, I worry that any gain brought by `where` vs. `argwhere` will be lost in this last loop due to `zip(*...)`. Just let me know if that is the case and I will happily delete this answer.

Comment: How np.flatnonzero() can be used in a 2D array and what if we are interested in values that are bigger than a number other than zero?

Comment: @BehzadJamali `flatnonzero` is not used directly on your data but rather on the result of the comparison (arr > 0.05). For 2D data use `nonzero()` which is pretty much the same as `where()`.

Comment: @BehzadJamali Oh, I just re-read your question and I see that you mention you are dealing with 2D arrays. Editing my answer...

Comment: I'm checking the solution.

Comment: @BehzadJamali I added an example that also show that you will need to use `zip(*...)` in your inner loop which could kill any performance gains.

Comment: Why you think I need to use 'zip'? can't I just use `Xs = index_of_pixels_with_excess_volume[0]` and `Ys = index_of_pixels_with_excess_volume[1]` and then iterate through them?

Comment: `zip(*...)` is a just a list version of the array `transpose`.

Comment: @BehzadJamali Of course you can modify your code to deal with the new structure of the results from `where()` vs. `argwhere()`. I was just trying to preserve the use of `pixel` as a list of two indices. If you can modify your code to use directly the output from `where` then you may salvage something...

Comment: @BehzadJamali By the way, a quick test shows that `for p in zip(*idx)` is slightly faster than the old `for p in idx` (where "old" `idx` is the output from `argwhere` while "new" `idx` is output from `where`).

Comment: Indices from `flatnonzero` can be `unraveled`.

Comment: @hpaulj True and I knew that. Unfortunately I did my tests with `flatnonzero` when I mistakenly thought that arrays are 1D and I never returned to testing `flatnonzero` again with 2D.

Comment: @hpaulj Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to my question for those who might be interested: I found "Code Vectorization" by using numpy tricks would significantly speed-up the run time by eliminating `for` or `while` loops and `numpy.where()`. I found these two websites very helpful in explaining code vectorization.

https://github.com/rougier/from-python-to-numpy/blob/master/04-code-vectorization.rst#id36

https://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/teaching/numpy/numpy.html