# Find index of a vector inside a matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, search, where-clause

Given a matrix (`numpy` array) `A` and a vector `v`.

```
A = np.array([[5,0],[1,-2],[0,2],[-1,3],[1,2]])
v = np.array([0,2])
```

What is the best way to get the index of the vector v in the matrix A (in this case one should get 2).

Comment: If the values are unique (distinct), how about `A[A == v][2]` ?

Answer (score 1):

This does it:

```
np.argwhere((v == A).all(1))
```

```
Out[82]: array([[2]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

If by *best* you mean *fastest*, after thorough experimentation user hpaulj [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47068979/13018268) that `np.flatnonzero` is a much faster alternative to `np.argwhere`. You can use it this way:

```
np.flatnonzero((v==A).all(1))[0]
```

Output:

```
2
```