# Numpy 2d array, obtain indexes of rows where specified column indexes equal 1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array like so, which will only ever have 0, 1 values.

```
a = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0],  # Indexes 0 and 2 == 1
             [0, 1, 1, 0],   # Indexes 1 and 2 == 1
             [0, 1, 0, 1],   # Indexes 1 and 3 == 1
             [0, 1, 1, 1]])  # Indexes 1, 2, and 3 == 1
```

What I'd like to do is to get the indices of every row where a pair of column indexes passed are all equal to 1.

For example, if the function doing this is `get_rows`, `get_rows(a, [1, 3])`, should return [2, 3], because the rows at indexes 2 and 3 have column indexes 1 and 3 equal to 1.  Similarly,  `get_rows(a, [1, 2])` should return [1, 3].

I know how to do this in a Pandas dataframe, but I'd like to stick to using pure numpy for this one.  I tried using `np.where` in some form like

```
np.where( ((a[i1 - 1] == 1) & (a[i2 - 1] == 1) ))
```

but this doesn't seem to give me what I want, and wouldn't work for varying number of passed indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
col_idx = [1, 2]
np.where(a[:,col_idx].all(axis=1))[0]
```

You can use ANY column indexes you want to pass to it. It is quite self explanatory that extracts columns and searches for rows with all 1s in there using np.where.

*EDIT*: per @Mad Physicist recommendation, here is another similar solution:

```
np.flatnonzero(a[:,col_idx].all(axis=1))
```

Output example for your input:

```
[1 3]
```

Comment: `nonzero` is better than `where` in this case. In fact, you can use `flatnonzero`

Comment: @MadPhysicist, could you help me understand why `flatnonzero` is better than `where`?  Is it performance related?

Comment: @JulianDrago At least performance boost. Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068017/alternative-to-numpy-argwhere-to-speed-up-for-loop-in-python

Comment: @JulianDrago, because `where` is documented to be a wrapper for `nonzero` in this case, and `flatnonzero` is more efficient than `nonzero` if you only want one return value, especially if the input is 1D.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Try this.

### Code - Logic

- Find row and column indices where the given columns (`target_col_index`) have `1`.
- Select only those rows where column indices match the `target_col_index`.
- Narrow down the result by checking the which row indices have results matching to the same number of columns as was in `target_col_index`.

```py
import numpy as np

target_col_index = [1,2]
target_row_index = get_row_index(a, target_col_index)
print(target_row_index)

## Output
# [1,3]

## Other cases tested
# test_col_indexes = [ [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3], [0,1,3], [1,2,3] ]
# returned_row_indexes = [ [], [0], [], [1,3], [2,3], [3], [], [3] ]
```

### Code - Custom Function

```py
def get_row_index(arr, target_col_index=None):
    if target_col_index is None:
        return None
    else:
        row_index, col_index = np.where(arr==1)
        result = row_index[np.isin(col_index, target_col_index)]
        rows, counts = np.unique(result, return_counts=True)
        target_row_index = rows[counts==len(target_col_index)]
        return target_row_index
```

### Dummy Data

```py
a = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0],  # Indexes 0 and 2 == 1
            [0, 1, 1, 0],   # Indexes 1 and 2 == 1
            [0, 1, 0, 1],   # Indexes 1 and 3 == 1
            [0, 1, 1, 1]])  # Indexes 1, 2, and 3 == 1
```

Comment: If the argument passed is [1, 2], the answer returned should be values [1, 3], because the rows at index 1 and at index 3 have those col indexes equal to 1.  Output of {0, 1, 2, 3} isn't correct, it's all the rows in the array.

Comment: Thank you. I was in the process of updating the answer. Please check now.